# Stored procedure using table with recipients

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a table I would like split and emailed to the corresponding staff member of that department, I have two tables, Table 1 contains all the transaction data against the department and is live, Table 2 is static which essentially lists the staff member who is responsible for the each department.

I need to split up table 1 by Department then lookup the email for the corresponding staff member from table2 and send the split table.

Table 1:

```
| Customer | ? | Department
| Customer | ? | Department1
| Customer | ? | Department2
```

Table2:

```
| Department  | Staff  | Email
| Department1 | Staff1 | Email
| Department2 | Staff2 | Email
```

I was wondering, would it be possible to create a stored procedure to do this or would I have to create a subscription in SSRS for each individual staff member?

Thanks,

Neil

Comment: Definitely possible 

Comment: haha thanks Scsimon, now how would one go about this?

Comment: There are a few ways you could go about this I suppose. The first question that needs to be addressed is would the report be ran once a day, on an adoc basis, by the user or automated? etc. All things to consider. You can limit the results of Table1 with Table2 of course with a simple join, and use `sp_send_dbmail` to send the result set. Or you could set a subscription in SRRS with the parameter being the Staff ID/Name if you need the results formatted a specific way.

Comment: Would be scheduled for a monday morning 8:00 (nice wake up call!). I didnt want to have to create seperate subscriptions and then pass a set parameter for each department, I wanted it to be able to be a bit flexible and would save having to amend all subscriptions when a table could just be amended.

Comment: Then i would look into the `sp_send_dbmail` option but i feel like at some point you would need a cursor, so another option would be an SSIS job.

Answer (score 1):

I would thoroughly recommend making a simple SSRS report and distributing it via a Data Driven Subscription.  The queries below will get you started on your data extracts and you can follow a guide [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/data-driven-subscription-in-ssrs-2008-r2.html) on how to set up an SSRS Data Driven Subscription.

They are very simple to create, you only need the one subscription to send an email to every Department and they are very easy to maintain, even by someone else with no idea what it does.

```
declare @t1 table(Cust nvarchar(100)
                ,Cols nvarchar(100)
                ,Dept nvarchar(100)
                )
declare @t2 table(Dept nvarchar(100)
                ,Staff nvarchar(100)
                ,Email nvarchar(100)
                )

insert into @t1 Values
 ('Customer','?','Department1')
,('Customer','?','Department2')
,('Customer','?','Department3')

insert into @t2 Values
 ('Department1','Staff1','Email1')
,('Department2','Staff2','Email2')
,('Department3','Staff3','Email3')


-- Use this query in your Data Driven Subscription to generate the list of Departments and their respective Emails:
select distinct t1.Dept
                ,t2.Email
from @t1 t1
    left join @t2 t2
        on(t1.Dept = t2.Dept)

-- Then use this query in your report to list out the contents of Table 1, matching the @SSRSDeptParameter value in the Data Driven Subscription options.
select t1.Cust
        ,t1.Cols
        ,t1.Dept
        ,t2.Email
from @t1 t1
    left join @t2 t2
        on(t1.Dept = t2.Dept)
where @t1.Dept = @SSRSDeptParameter
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, unfortunately the version of SSRS we are using does not have data driven subscriptions so we just have to rely on a SP.

Comment: @NeilNorris  Slightly overdue an upgrade then?  What is stopping you from upgrading your SQL Version?

Comment: IT department being a pain. Figured I should create a master table with all the data next to the associated staff members email address, then all I have to do is somehow get the SP to split the table up into its staff members and send the corresponding partition to them.

Comment: @NeilNorris  Then you are going to have to look at other options, like the combination of a cursor and dbmail mentioned elsewhere or another program like SSIS/Other Third Party software.

Comment: Figured as much if i want it to be straight forward, some guy who no longer works with us wrote a similiar thing for our system which works but its all types of crazy and hard to break down